Spatial indexes not being used despite existing
Here is my query:
explain analyze
with pings as ( -- ================= SELECTING JOINED data with join conditions -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
        select 
          u."imei" as u_imei, 
          a."imei" as a_imei, 
          u.t as u_ping_time, 
          a.t as a_ping_time, 
          u_ping_id, 
          a_ping_id 
        from 

(-- ================= SELECTING Parent INFO [imei, geom, generatedAt, pingID] -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
            select 
              p.imei, 
              p."geoJson" as geom,
              --st_transform(p."geoJson", 32643) as geom, 
              "generatedAt" as t, 
              p."ID" as u_ping_id 
            from 
              campaign_pings p 
            
              
              where "generatedAt"::date ='2024-05-04'
              
              and 
              
              p.imei in (
                select 
                  assets."IMEI" 
                from 
                  campaign_staff staff 
                  left join campaign_staff_info csi on csi."campaignStaffID"=staff."ID" and csi."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_info csi2 where csi2."campaignStaffID" = csi."campaignStaffID" and csi2.date <= '2024-05-04')
                  left join campaign_staff_assets csa on csa."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and csa."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= csa."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<='2024-05-04')
                  left join campaign_area_assets caa on caa."assetID" = csa."assetID" 
                  and caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = csa."campaignScopeID" 
                  left join assets assets on assets."ID" = caa."assetID" 
                  left join staff_type staff_type ON staff_type."ID" = staff."staffTypeID"
                  left join campaign_asset_status cas  on cas."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and cas."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status cas2 where cas2."campaignStaffID"= cas."campaignStaffID" and cas2.date<='2024-05-04')
                where 
                  caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = 'afe99c7e-a406-4765-a0b6-7cf4e8efb28c'--'afe99c7e-a406-4765-a0b6-7cf4e8efb28c' 
                  and assets."IMEI" is not null 
                  and staff_type."ID" = '93313048-4e75-4e91-9bcd-44897a6df7c7' -- AIC ID
                  and (cas.status is null or cas.status  <> 'DeployedWoPhone')
                  and ((csi.number is null) or (csi.number <> '0'))
              )
          ) u 
          left join ( -- ================= SELECTING child INFO [imei, geom, generatedAt, pingID] -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
            SELECT 
              p.imei, 
              p."ID" as a_ping_id, 
              p."geoJson" as geom,
              --st_transform(p."geoJson", 32643) as geom, 
              "generatedAt" as t 
            FROM 
              campaign_pings p 
              
              where "generatedAt"::date ='2024-05-04'
              
              and 
              
              p.imei in (
                select 
                  assets."IMEI" 
                from 
                  campaign_staff staff 
                  left join campaign_staff_assets csa on csa."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and csa."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= csa."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<='2024-05-04')
                  left join campaign_area_assets caa on caa."assetID" = csa."assetID" 
                  and caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = csa."campaignScopeID" 
                  left join assets assets on assets."ID" = caa."assetID" 
                  left join staff_type staff_type ON staff_type."ID" = staff."staffTypeID"
                  left join campaign_asset_status cas  on cas."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and cas."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status cas2 where cas2."campaignStaffID"= cas."campaignStaffID" and cas2.date<='2024-05-04')
                where 
                  caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = 'afe99c7e-a406-4765-a0b6-7cf4e8efb28c'--'afe99c7e-a406-4765-a0b6-7cf4e8efb28c' 
                  and assets."IMEI" is not null 
                  and staff_type."ID" = 'acf0cc70-7c92-474d-82af-f37494f94c09' --team ID
                  and (cas.status is null or cas.status  <> 'DeployedWoPhone')
              )
          ) a on ST_DWithin(u."geom"::geography, a."geom"::geography, 30) 
          and a.t BETWEEN u.t - INTERVAL '30 seconds' 
          and u.t + INTERVAL '30 seconds' 
          where 
          a.imei is not null
      )
      

Here is the resulting query plan -
Aggregate  (cost=44537.75..44537.76 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=4039.488..4039.525 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=43198.89..44537.74 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2181.685..4038.525 rows=3562 loops=1)
        Join Filter: ((p_1."generatedAt" >= (p."generatedAt" - '00:00:30'::interval)) AND (p_1."generatedAt" <= (p."generatedAt" + '00:00:30'::interval)) AND st_dwithin((p."geoJson")::geography, (p_1."geoJson")::geography, '30'::double precision, true))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 6158918
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7822.71..7878.95 rows=7 width=40) (actual time=140.469..599.031 rows=1268 loops=1)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=6680.20..6680.21 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=8.532..8.579 rows=5 loops=1)
                    Group Key: (assets."IMEI")::text
                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.41..6680.20 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=6.940..8.530 rows=5 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((cas.status IS NULL) OR (cas.status <> 'DeployedWoPhone'::campaign_asset_status_status_enum))
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..6538.75 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6.621..7.734 rows=5 loops=1)
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..6537.62 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=6.603..7.679 rows=5 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..6531.42 rows=1 width=46) (actual time=6.563..7.605 rows=5 loops=1)
                                            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..6527.11 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=6.528..7.530 rows=5 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: ((csi.number IS NULL) OR ((csi.number)::text <> '0'::text))
                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..6518.01 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=6.390..7.138 rows=5 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on campaign_staff staff  (cost=0.00..190.90 rows=697 width=32) (actual time=0.192..2.459 rows=697 loops=1)
                                                              Filter: ("staffTypeID" = '93313048-4e75-4e91-9bcd-44897a6df7c7'::uuid)
                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 5135
                                                        ->  Index Scan using "REL_64f385ec0768494c47b41bfc53" on campaign_staff_assets csa  (cost=0.28..9.07 rows=1 width=39) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=697)
                                                              Index Cond: ("campaignStaffID" = staff."ID")
                                                              Filter: (("campaignScopeID" = 'afe99c7e-a406-4765-a0b6-7cf4e8efb28c'::uuid) AND (date = (SubPlan 4)))
                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                                              SubPlan 4
                                                                ->  Result  (cost=4.30..4.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=25)
                                                                      InitPlan 3 (returns $3)
                                                                        ->  Limit  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=25)
                                                                              ->  Index Only Scan Backward using "REL_64f385ec0768494c47b41bfc53" on campaign_staff_assets cs2  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=25)
                                                                                    Index Cond: (("campaignStaffID" = csa."campaignStaffID") AND (date IS NOT NULL) AND (date <= '2024-05-04'::date))
                                                                                    Heap Fetches: 0
                                                  ->  Index Scan using "STAFF_INFO_PK" on campaign_staff_info csi  (cost=0.28..9.09 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.062..0.076 rows=1 loops=5)
                                                        Index Cond: ("campaignStaffID" = staff."ID")
                                                        Filter: (date = (SubPlan 2))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 4
                                                        SubPlan 2
                                                          ->  Result  (cost=4.30..4.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=25)
                                                                InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                                                                  ->  Limit  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=25)
                                                                        ->  Index Only Scan Backward using "STAFF_INFO_PK" on campaign_staff_info csi2  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=25)
                                                                              Index Cond: (("campaignStaffID" = csi."campaignStaffID") AND (date IS NOT NULL) AND (date <= '2024-05-04'::date))
                                                                              Heap Fetches: 0
                                            ->  Index Only Scan using "PK_AreaAssets" on campaign_area_assets caa  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=5)
                                                  Index Cond: (("assetID" = (csa."assetID")::text) AND ("campaignScopeAreaID" = 'afe99c7e-a406-4765-a0b6-7cf4e8efb28c'::uuid))
                                                  Heap Fetches: 0
                                      ->  Index Scan using "PK_2da8ab8bece3ae8da02e5bf1c93" on assets  (cost=0.29..6.20 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=5)
                                            Index Cond: (("ID")::text = (caa."assetID")::text)
                                            Filter: ("IMEI" IS NOT NULL)
                                ->  Seq Scan on staff_type  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=5)
                                      Filter: ("ID" = '93313048-4e75-4e91-9bcd-44897a6df7c7'::uuid)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 8
                          ->  Index Scan using "StaffAssetStatus" on campaign_asset_status cas  (cost=0.28..141.44 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.139..0.156 rows=1 loops=5)
                                Index Cond: ("campaignStaffID" = staff."ID")
                                Filter: (date = (SubPlan 6))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                                SubPlan 6
                                  ->  Result  (cost=43.16..43.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=20)
                                        InitPlan 5 (returns $5)
                                          ->  Limit  (cost=0.28..43.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=20)
                                                ->  Index Only Scan Backward using "StaffAssetStatus" on campaign_asset_status cas2  (cost=0.28..86.05 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=20)
                                                      Index Cond: ((date IS NOT NULL) AND (date <= '2024-05-04'::date) AND ("campaignStaffID" = cas."campaignStaffID"))
                                                      Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on campaign_pings p  (cost=1142.50..1198.58 rows=16 width=55) (actual time=112.080..117.855 rows=254 loops=5)
                    Recheck Cond: (((imei)::text = (assets."IMEI")::text) AND (("generatedAt")::date = '2024-05-04'::date))
                    Heap Blocks: exact=1268
                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1142.50..1142.50 rows=16 width=0) (actual time=112.000..112.001 rows=0 loops=5)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cp_imei_idx  (cost=0.00..31.15 rows=3124 width=0) (actual time=0.431..0.431 rows=2329 loops=5)
                                Index Cond: ((imei)::text = (assets."IMEI")::text)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on campaing_pings_generatedat_date  (cost=0.00..1086.24 rows=99440 width=0) (actual time=111.246..111.246 rows=2173686 loops=5)
                                Index Cond: (("generatedAt")::date = '2024-05-04'::date)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=35376.18..35432.46 rows=7 width=40) (actual time=0.128..1.915 rows=4860 loops=1268)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=35376.18..35432.43 rows=7 width=40) (actual time=161.405..2030.119 rows=4860 loops=1)
                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=34225.87..34225.88 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=55.032..55.143 rows=17 loops=1)
                          Group Key: (assets_1."IMEI")::text
                          Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.85..34225.87 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=26.549..54.993 rows=17 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((cas_1.status IS NULL) OR (cas_1.status <> 'DeployedWoPhone'::campaign_asset_status_status_enum))
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..34084.46 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=26.373..52.832 rows=17 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..34083.33 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=26.359..52.653 rows=17 loops=1)
                                            Join Filter: ((csa_1."assetID")::text = (caa_1."assetID")::text)
                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..34080.88 rows=1 width=78) (actual time=26.317..52.453 rows=17 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..34072.58 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=26.237..52.130 rows=17 loops=1)
                                                        Join Filter: (staff_1."ID" = csa_1."campaignStaffID")
                                                        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 167342
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on campaign_staff_assets csa_1  (cost=0.00..33825.38 rows=1 width=39) (actual time=1.119..2.299 rows=38 loops=1)
                                                              Filter: (("campaignScopeID" = 'afe99c7e-a406-4765-a0b6-7cf4e8efb28c'::uuid) AND (date = (SubPlan 8)))
                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 7748
                                                              SubPlan 8
                                                                ->  Result  (cost=4.30..4.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=130)
                                                                      InitPlan 7 (returns $7)
                                                                        ->  Limit  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=130)
                                                                              ->  Index Only Scan Backward using "REL_64f385ec0768494c47b41bfc53" on campaign_staff_assets cs2_1  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=130)
                                                                                    Index Cond: (("campaignStaffID" = csa_1."campaignStaffID") AND (date IS NOT NULL) AND (date <= '2024-05-04'::date))
                                                                                    Heap Fetches: 0
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on campaign_staff staff_1  (cost=0.00..190.90 rows=4504 width=32) (actual time=0.029..0.983 rows=4404 loops=38)
                                                              Filter: ("staffTypeID" = 'acf0cc70-7c92-474d-82af-f37494f94c09'::uuid)
                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 1285
                                                  ->  Index Scan using "PK_2da8ab8bece3ae8da02e5bf1c93" on assets assets_1  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=17)
                                                        Index Cond: (("ID")::text = (csa_1."assetID")::text)
                                                        Filter: ("IMEI" IS NOT NULL)
                                            ->  Index Only Scan using "PK_AreaAssets" on campaign_area_assets caa_1  (cost=0.28..2.44 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=17)
                                                  Index Cond: (("assetID" = (assets_1."ID")::text) AND ("campaignScopeAreaID" = 'afe99c7e-a406-4765-a0b6-7cf4e8efb28c'::uuid))
                                                  Heap Fetches: 0
                                      ->  Seq Scan on staff_type staff_type_1  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=17)
                                            Filter: ("ID" = 'acf0cc70-7c92-474d-82af-f37494f94c09'::uuid)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 8
                                ->  Index Scan using "StaffAssetStatus" on campaign_asset_status cas_1  (cost=0.28..141.40 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.109..0.124 rows=1 loops=17)
                                      Index Cond: ("campaignStaffID" = staff_1."ID")
                                      Filter: (date = (SubPlan 10))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                      SubPlan 10
                                        ->  Result  (cost=43.16..43.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=49)
                                              InitPlan 9 (returns $9)
                                                ->  Limit  (cost=0.28..43.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=49)
                                                      ->  Index Only Scan Backward using "StaffAssetStatus" on campaign_asset_status cas2_1  (cost=0.28..86.05 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=49)
                                                            Index Cond: ((date IS NOT NULL) AND (date <= '2024-05-04'::date) AND ("campaignStaffID" = cas_1."campaignStaffID"))
                                                            Heap Fetches: 0
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on campaign_pings p_1  (cost=1150.31..1206.39 rows=16 width=55) (actual time=110.494..115.487 rows=286 loops=17)
                          Recheck Cond: (((imei)::text = (assets_1."IMEI")::text) AND (imei IS NOT NULL) AND (("generatedAt")::date = '2024-05-04'::date))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=4841
                          ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1150.31..1150.31 rows=16 width=0) (actual time=110.397..110.397 rows=0 loops=17)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cp_imei_idx  (cost=0.00..38.96 rows=3124 width=0) (actual time=0.460..0.460 rows=2361 loops=17)
                                      Index Cond: (((imei)::text = (assets_1."IMEI")::text) AND (imei IS NOT NULL))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on campaing_pings_generatedat_date  (cost=0.00..1086.24 rows=99440 width=0) (actual time=109.508..109.508 rows=2173686 loops=17)
                                      Index Cond: (("generatedAt")::date = '2024-05-04'::date)
Planning Time: 8.476 ms
Execution Time: 4041.460 ms

Here are the table indexes:
PK_953f5825000b2b7d6583b3bd987  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_953f5825000b2b7d6583b3bd987" ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("ID")
campaing_pings_createdat_date   CREATE INDEX campaing_pings_createdat_date ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ((("createdAt")::date))
campaing_pings_generatedat_date CREATE INDEX campaing_pings_generatedat_date ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ((("generatedAt")::date))
cp_date_idx CREATE INDEX cp_date_idx ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("generatedAt")
cp_geoJson_idx  CREATE INDEX "cp_geoJson_idx" ON public.campaign_pings USING gist ("geoJson")
cp_idx_createdat    CREATE INDEX cp_idx_createdat ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("createdAt")
cp_imei_hash    CREATE INDEX cp_imei_hash ON public.campaign_pings USING hash (imei)
cp_imei_idx CREATE INDEX cp_imei_idx ON public.campaign_pings USING btree (imei)
cp_imeidate_idx CREATE INDEX cp_imeidate_idx ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("generatedAt", imei)
gist_geog_cp_geojson    CREATE INDEX gist_geog_cp_geojson ON public.campaign_pings USING gist (geography("geoJson")) 


Does your database have up to date statistics?

Apparently the database has decided that using the index doesn't add anything. What is the actual problem, is the query slow? Could you add a question to your question? What does the table look like?

Also, I have a feeling this question better fits https://dba.stackexchange.com/

You are ST_Transform'ing your "geoJson" geometries - that is not covered by any of the two spatial indexes! Note that, with some exceptions for hashable joins, only one index per relation can get utilized - a decision made by the planner mostly over table statistics.

@geozelot I am now making use of the geography index by using p."geoJson" as geom (not transforming anymore), and at the end doing ST_DWithin(u."geom"::geography, a."geom"::geography, 30). Still the geoJson column index is not mentioned in the query plan.

@geozelot I have updated the question with these changes

Also, should I replace my left join with inner join?

That depends on what you are trying to do - keep those rows from u in the result that have no matches in a in their spatiotemporal proximity, or not - and both JOINs are fine, syntactically. Your query spends half its time on finding pings by date, and the other half to filter those from the join result that are not in spatiotemporal proximity - and it vastly underestimates result rows. Run a VACUUM ANALYZE on the core tables, and experiment with an index on the timestamp value of "createdAt" rather than the date (use a BETWEEN filter here, too).

If you get that data incrementally - strictly ordered by timestamp - and your table is considerably large (>~100 million rows), consider a BRIN index on the timestamp column. But do not simply add dozens of indexes in hopes of performance gain - it will backfire at you.

@geozelot - adding an index on the timestamp column seemed like a great idea but unfortunately did not help. Does the query need any re-structuring before it can benefit from this new index? thanks so much.

Do I need to delete the existing timestamp::date index first?

Have you considered building your query from the scratch starting from a bare minimal and adding extra components one by one? Perhaps you can find when the optimizer stops utilizing the spatial index.
